# how to transform following xml to another xml using xslt summary input xml element value should become the output xml tag with their values at runtime

Tags: xml, xslt

if input.xml have key value pairs this may be large file so run time output should geneate key become the output tag name and value will be its value using xslt
Input.xml

```
            <keyValueStr>
                <key>memberId </key>
                <value>12345</value>
            </keyValueStr>
            <keyValueStr>
                <key>mbrAccountNumber</key>
                <value>CO12345</value>
            </keyValueStr>
            <keyValueStr>
                <key>grId</key>
                <value>4568667</value>
            </keyValueStr>
            <keyValueStr>
                <key>abc </key>
                <value>111111</value>
            </keyValueStr>
            <keyValueStr>
                <key>def</key>
                <value>22222</value>
            </keyValueStr>
            <keyValueStr>
                <key>ghi</key>
                <value>33333</value>
            </keyValueStr>
```

```
**output should like this:**
<memberMinimumInfoRequest>
            <memberid>12345</memberId>
            <mbrAccountNumber>CO12345</mbrAccountNumber>
            <grId>4568667</grId>
            <abc>111111</abc>
            <def>22222</def>
            <ghi>33333</ghi>
</memberMinimumInfoRequest>
```

Comment: **1.** Please post a minimal but **complete** example of your input. -- **2.** The success of the required task depends on the `key` values being valid element names; even in your example not all of them are. --**3.** Please indicate whether using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If the information for each member starts with a `MemberId` key, then in the template for the containing element you can use `xsl:for-each-group` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) to select each member's information and process it, e.g.:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="keyValueStr"
                    group-starting-with="keyValueStr[. eq 'memberId ']">
  <memberMinimumInfoRequest>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
  </memberMinimumInfoRequest>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

(Should there really be a space in 'memberId '?)